# WPF Prism: Regions show up as new windows

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a WPF application using Prism. I set up my regions inside a shell application as ContentControls inside Shell.xaml

Everything works fine except I do not want the regions to be separate windows. I want them embedded in the main window unless otherwise specified to be a child window of the shell. What is the trick?

Comment: Your question is little unclear. What do you mean by "except I do not want the regions to be separate windows". You mentioned in your question you are adding regions inside your shell.xaml, so how it is coming as a separate windows.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show how are you defining the regions. If regions are defined in the shell, they would indeed be configuring the different region areas on the Shell's window. We would give you better support if you could give us more context on the **Views** and **Regions** definition and registration.

Comment: Actually the shell application itself was creating two windows. It had nothing to do with regions and I can't explain why the app was doing that. I just created a new shell app from scratch and it worked fine.